# Why connecting Information and Verses

Tags: tractate-brachot, oral-torah, chazal, written-torah

There is a Pasuk in [Shmot 24:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that says:

> I will give you the stone tablets, the Law and the commandments, which I have written to instruct them.

The Gemara in [Berachot 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.5a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that the tablets refer to the "10 commandmants", "Law" to the Torah, and the word "written" to the writings and Prophets and the word "commandments" to the Mishna and the word "to instruct them" to the Gemara. This all comes to teach us that all of the above was given on Mt. Sinai.

As far as I understand, Chazal have a tradition about the origin of the Oral Torah and a verse about the 10 commandments and try to connect them.

It is as if I try to read oral Information given by A into a letter given by A.

Why do Chazal saw the need to do that?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How the sages connected these five things refer to Torah, Neviim, Mishnah and Gemara? Are you asking where this insight came from?

Comment: No I am asking why the sages connect this tradition (that all came from Sinai) with the Verse that in context speaks about something else.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your question - that the giving of the 10 commandments is not the same as the giving of everything else (mishna gemara etc.) - isn't necessarily correct. For example, Rav Saadya Gaon in his count of the 613 mitzvot, derives each mitzva from one of the 10 commandments. Meaning the giving of the 10 commandments *was* the giving of everything else, in which case learning it from the passuk which talks about the 10 commandments makes a lot of sense.

But even if that point is debatable, Chaza"l are teaching us an important lesson: that everything was given to Moshe on Har Sinai. Since the only thing that is actually mentioned in the passukim as having been given on Har Sinai is the 10 commandments, Chaza"l need to show us where this understanding is visible in the passukim, even if it's not the simple understanding of the passuk in context.